# Why do audits count toward the maximum number of reviews in a queue?

Tags: support, review-audits

What happened:

1. I reviewed a post, which was an audit.
2. I was then given the message "Thank you for reviewing 20 Suggested Edits today."

Question:

Why does an audit count toward the maximum 20 reviews?

Comment: just happened to me I was kinda shocked

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because audits also count towards your review stats for badges as an action (assuming you passed). That means it could easily be abused by skipping all the normal posts and just keeping an eye out for audits, which would allow you to rack up a potentially infinite amount of actions without ever hitting a daily limit.

If you don't want audits to count towards the daily limit, then they can't count towards *anything*. It's one or the other; you can't have the best of both worlds.

Comment: I'd rather have them not count toward anything. They are pseudo actions, just like Meta posts. Honestly, I'd rather the auditing system were replaced with a real, human-run auditing system, but that's another Meta topic.

Comment: I also think counting them is stupid because (a) an action useful for this site could've been taken instead of reviewing an audit and (b) audits are so easy that you shouldn't get a badge score for them.