# What happens if I skip a review audit?

Tags: support, review, review-audits

As the title states, I can't find any record of what happens if I hit the `Skip` button on a review item that happened to be an audit.

[This brilliant answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/288284) doesn't seem to cover it.

Will I be flagged if I happen to skip one? [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188894/review-ban-after-skipping-a-review) seemed to suggest so, but after examining the answers, it looks like a false positive.

Will I in any way be notified that it was an audit? From [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216547/show-a-message-when-user-skips-a-review-audit), it would seem I will not, but there is no confirmation on that.

Comment: Is this based on your observation @Roombatron5000, or are there any other sources to this?

Answer (score 12):

Generally, nothing. As with any other review task, you *should* skip an audit if you're just not sure what to do.

The exception to this is if you *only* skip audits. And you skip them consistently. I track that, and might decide to give you a break from reviewing if I see that happening a lot.

Why? Because, as I said above, you should try to skip *any* task you're not comfortable making a decision on. If the only tasks you can't decide are the ones created to see if you're paying attention, you might have simply decided that paying attention is too much work...

Comment: He knows if you've been bad or good, so be good for goodness sake.

Comment: Any mod can track that on any site, or does it require CM power?

Comment: Mods can track it to an extent, and of course hand out bans as they see fit; I just have a particular query customized for this sole purpose.

Comment: Neat, better keep this in mind!!

Comment: If I consistently skip audits, that means I can decide, which is audit and which isn't... I think the only reason to consistently skip them to annoy the mods on a non-constructive way (the constructive way to annoy them is to complain their power misuses).

Comment: "*I track that*" great, now when I do reviews I'll have a vision of your wobbly head ninjering behind me

Comment: @peterh one fairly legitimate reason to skip audits I can think of is to save (_limited_) review actions for doing actual stuff. Related: [Why do audits count toward the maximum number of reviews in a queue?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/197875/165773)

Comment: @James Well, Shog's location *is* "Not looking over your shoulder" ....but he just might be ;-)

Comment: There are multiple legit reasons to skip audits, @peterh. There are not so many legit reasons for active reviewers to skip *only* audits.

Comment: @Shog9 I'm not so sure if your logic in the post is correct. You say *The exception to this is if you only skip audits.* and you obviously do not realize that if the audits are noticed by the user they already caught his attention. I googled this question because skipping review audit is way faster than rejecting it. So this is a reason, for me as a reviewer, to skip those obvious review audits.